# How to add live camera scan with "react-qr-reader" in React App?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, qr-code

Hi I was trying to make a web qr scanner with next js. but I am not understanding how to take live video to scan a qr code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const QrReader = dynamic(
  () => import("react-qr-reader").then((mod) => mod.QrReader),
  { ssr: false }
);
class Index extends Component {
  state = {
    result: "No result",
  };

  handleScan = (data) => {
    if (data) {
      this.setState({
        result: data,
      });
    }
  };
  handleError = (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <QrReader
          delay={300}
          onError={this.handleError}
          onScan={this.handleScan}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
        />
        <p>{this.state.result}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Index;
```

how can I add a live camera option to get scan from webcam.

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const QrReader = dynamic(() => import('react-qr-reader'), {
    ssr: false
})

class Index extends Component {
    state = {
      result: "No result",
    };
  
    handleScan = (data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.setState({
          result: data,
        });
      }
    };
    handleError = (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    };
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <QrReader
            delay={300}
            onError={this.handleError}
            onScan={this.handleScan}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          />
          <p>{this.state.result}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Index;
```

https://github.com/JodusNodus/react-qr-reader/issues/96